# Scoped lock_guard Not Releasing Mutex in Static Method

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, static-methods, lock-guard

**Platform** *Debian 9* | *ARM*

I have a class that is used to store thread IDs on a `std::list` and then print the list as part of the shutdown procedure. There are two static methods: `AddId()` and `PrintIds()`. Since the static methods are used by several threads, the list access is protected with a `std::mutex`. I have come across two issues that have me baffled and they may be related. I hope one of you can help explain what I am missing.

***Note** I first used scoped `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`s and have temporarily settled on the `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`s that are shown in the code for the reasons explained herein.*

**Issue 1**  When the program starts, all threads call `ThreadMgr::AddId()`, which adds the thread id to the list along with a string name. That seems to work fine. However, when `ThreadMgr::PrintIds()` is called during the shutdown procedure, the `std::mutex` is still locked and the `std::lock_guard` blocks. While testing, I unlocked the `std::mutex` in the line preceding the `std::lock_guard`--which is [undefined behavior](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/unlock/) if it wasn't locked by the calling thread--and then it worked as expected. The only place the `std::mutex` is used is in these two methods, and with the `std::lock_guard` being scoped, the `std::mutex` should have been unlocked with every method call. I went through several iterations of locking and unlocking the `std::mutex` directly, using `std::unique_lock`s, etc. I eventually found a somewhat workable solution using the `std::unique_lock`s that are in the code provided here. However, that too has me baffled.

The `std::unique_lock`s work if I use `std::adopt_lock`, but only in `ThreadMgr::PrintIds()`. If I use `std::adopt_lock` in `ThreadMgr::AddId()`, then I get a segmentation fault whenever `ThreadMgr::PrintIds()` is called.

**Issue 2** As previously stated, `ThreadMgr::AddId()` runs fine with either `std::lock_guard` or `std::unique_lock` when all threads call it on startup. However, there are UI sessions where each session spawns a thread. When `ThreadMgr::AddId()` is called from one of these session threads, both `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock` block like the `std::mutex` is already locked. So, `ThreadMgr::AddId()` works perfectly fine for every other thread, but not for the session threads that are started later.

If there is any other information I can provide to help get to a solution, let me know.

```
class ThreadMgr {
 public:
    ThreadMgr();
    ~ThreadMgr();
    static void AddId(std::string);
    static void PrintIds();

 private:
    static std::list<ThreadId> t_list;
    static std::mutex list_mtx;
};

/*Definition*/
ThreadMgr::ThreadMgr() {}
ThreadMgr::~ThreadMgr() {}

/*Static Members*/
void ThreadMgr::AddId(std::string name) {
    
    ThreadId t_id = getThreadId(name);
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(list_mtx);
        t_list.push_front(t_id);
    }

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cout_mtx);
    std::cout << "---Added id: " << t_id.tid << " for the " << name << " thread." << std::endl;

    return;
}
void ThreadMgr::PrintIds() {
    
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "\n**************************Thread Ids**************************\n";
    
    {   
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(list_mtx, std::adopt_lock);
        
        for (std::list<ThreadId>::iterator t = t_list.begin(); t != t_list.end(); t++) {
            oss << "---" << t->name << " : " << t->tid << '\n';
        }
    }
    oss << "************************End Thread Ids************************" << '\n';
            
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cout_mtx);
    std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
    
    return;
}

std::mutex ThreadMgr::list_mtx;
std::list<ThreadId> ThreadMgr::t_list;
```

```
int Main(){

    ThreadMgr::AddId("Main");

    std::thread MbServerT(MbServer);
    std::thread UiServerT(UiServer);

    while(run){
        //do stuff
    }
    
    ThreadMgr::PrintIds();
    
    if(MbServerT.joinable())
        MbServerT.join();

    if(UiServerT.joinable())
        UiServerT.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a `main` function and such, so that it's a [mcve] that people can test?

Comment: You might also like to throw ThreadSanitizer at it and see if it provides any hints.

Comment: In `ThreadMgr::PrintIds()`, why do you use `std::adopt_lock` argument in `std::unique_lock` ctor?

Comment: Are you doing any of these operations before `main` is entered or after `main` returned?

Comment: @Nate, I've added a basic `main`, but it's not minimal reproducible by copying/pasting. I will work on that in a bit. Thanks for the ThreadSanitizer suggestion. I am working through that now.

Comment: @Eugene, I landed at the `std::adopt_lock` as I was looking for a solution; it did not make sense to me. With Nate's ThreadSanitizer suggestion, I now know that it is actually unlocking the lock in an undefined manner. So, while it gets the immediate result I need, it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @ user17732522, no. The threads that are spawn are done so in main() and the methods are called before main() exits. In addition, all threads are joined before exiting main().